# What are available arguments for wp_oembed_get?

Tags: oembed

I used wp_oembed_get function to embed a YouTube video. It worked like it should.

Now I want to add a class to an embedded element. Is there an argument for this?

Can't find list of arguments for this function anywhere. I tried 'class' but it didn't work.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get

Comment: Even better, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_oembed_get/

Comment: Why, the question is answered. If you read the codex you see all parameters/arguments that don't include anything like a class parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of embedding is that you do not have control over how the embedded content is being styled and it is controlled by the server from which the content is embedded. The embedding server might allow some control over the embedded content via the URL parameters but to know how to achieve that you will have to consult the documentation of the provider.

You can enclose the embedded content in a div with whatever class you want, but that unlikely to help you much.

Comment: I was trying to achieve the structure that was set by the front-end dev. Now I understand that it was this structure that didn't make much sense. In fact he had a wrapping div and also a class for iframe...

Comment: In theory, for embedding providers that gives you actual HTML you can do some manipulation but I think most of them use iframes.